# Using the results of Fourier series to calculate the sum of another series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Given a function $$f(x)=x(\pi^2-x^2)$$

I calculated its Fourier series $$f(x)=x(\pi ^2-x^2)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{12(-1)^{n+1}\sin(nx)}{n^3}$$

Now i'm supposed to use this result to calculate the sum of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^3}$$

I tried to plug in a few values like $1/2 \pi or 3/2 \pi$ to make the $\sin$ go away but nothing worked out so far, how do i equate the denominator $(2n+1)^3$ and $(n)^3$

Thanks

Comment: One of the values you claimed to have tried would have actually worked to evaluate this sum. Try to take it in cases and remember that $n$ is a dummy variable that doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summation can be simplified as:
$$
\frac{x}{12} (\pi^2 - x^2) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sin(nx)}{n^3}
$$
for getting rid of $\sin(\theta)$. you can see $\theta=\frac{n\pi}{2}$ are special points. choose $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ (as you correctly guessed!):
$$
\sin (\frac{n\pi}{2}) = \begin{cases}
0 & n=2k \\
1 & n=4k+1\\
-1 & n=4k+3\\
\end{cases}
$$
so $\sin(nx)$ would be zero at even $n$. only nonzero elements are odd $n$'s. which in this case $(-1)^{n+1} =1$. so summation become:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin((2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2})}{(2n+1)^3}
$$
in which i just change $n$ to $2n+1$ because for even terms are zero and summation starts from $2n+1=1$, which in terms of $2n+1$ representation, n starts from $0$.
$$
\sin ((2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{n is even}\\
-1 & \text{n is odd}\\
\end{cases}
= (-1)^n
$$
so we get our series:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3} = \frac{1}{12}f(\frac{\pi}{2}) =\frac{3\pi^3}{12\times8} = 0.9689461462593693. 
$$
which you can confirm numerically.